# How can I prove $(k^2 -4)x^2 +4k$ can be a perfect square only if $k$ is a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, quadratics, vieta-jumping

> Proof $(k^2 - 4)x^2 +4k$ can be a perfect square only if $k$ is a perfect square.
>
> $k$ and $x$ are positive integers.

I have come to this formula while solving 1988 IMO #6 without using Vieta jumping, which means

$$ \frac{x^2+y^2}{xy+1} = k $$

can be expressed as

$$ y = \frac{1}{2} \left(k x - \sqrt{4 k - 4 x^2 + k^2 x^2} \right) $$

I thought if $4 k - 4 x^2 + k^2 x^2$, which is $(k^2 -4)x^2 +4k$ is a perfect square, eventually, $k$ will be an integer.

Comment: Ah, yes, beloved #6

Comment: The meaning of the question is not clear. Rewrote one task to another task. The answer to the problem is there, but no one is interested in it.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250172/when-is-fa-b-fraca2b21ab-a-perfect-square-rational-number/250300#250300   There are many discussions on this topic and Gauss wrote a book. And he showed that if there are two equivalent forms, then this is one equation. Therefore, the question is unclear. Do you want to solve one equation in different ways? Then it is necessary to say which method is needed.

Comment: @SGKw, If $k=n^2$  then   $(k^2-4)x^2+4k=y^2$ has  positive solutions as follows. 
We consider Pell equation $\ Y^2-dX^2=4$ then $(nY)^2-d(nX)^2=4n^2 $.  

On the other hand, let $k=n^2$ and $d=k^2-4$ then $(k^2-4)x^2+4k=y^2 \implies  y^2-dx^2=4n^2$.  

Hence we get $(x \ ,y)=(nX \ ,nY)$.

Comment: @Tomita What about the case where $k$ is not a perfect square? Does it guarantee that  $(k^2−4)x^2 + 4k$ can't be a perfect square?

Comment: @SGKw, I have no idea.

Comment: $(k^2-4)x^2+4k=(kx)^2-4(x^2-k)$ is the discriminant of the equation $X^2-kxX+(x^2-k)=0$ whose two solutions satisfy the equation of problem six of 1988 IMO. There are several known solutions of this problem which assures that we have integers if and only if $k$ is a square.

Comment: @Piquito I have searched nearly every solution to problem six of 1988 IMO (in MO). But I couldn't find answers related to my thought (or my knowledge was insufficient to understand some of the alternative solutions were related to my thought). So I have asked here with bounty.

Comment: @SGKw: The diophantine equation $\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy+1}=z^2$ has infinitely many solutions. I have proved this in a Congress in Latvia many years ago, maybe in 2010 (I don't have now the exacte reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\,a,k,x\,$ be positive integers, that is, $\,a,k,x\in\mathbb N\,.$

So far I cannot give a complete answer, but I will prove that

$\left(k^2-4\right)x^2+4k=a^2\;\implies\;k\leqslant x^2\,.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

***Proof :***

If $\;k>x^2\,,\,$ then

$\big(kx\big)^2\!\!<k^2x^2-4x^2+4k=a^2<k^2x^2+4kx<\!\big(kx+2\big)^2\;\;,$

therefore , $\;\;a^2=\big(kx+1\big)^2\;\;,$

$k^2x^2-4x^2+4k=k^2x^2+2kx+1\;\;\;,$

$4\big(k-x^2\big)=2kx+1\;\;\;,$

which is impossible because the LHS is an even number but the RHS is an odd number.

---

**Addendum :**

Now, I will prove that

$\left(k^2-4\right)x^2+4k=a^2\;\implies\;k=\lambda^2\;\;$ where $\;\lambda\in\mathbb N\,.$

***Proof :***

There are two possible cases :

$1)\quad1\leqslant k\leqslant 3\;;$

$2)\quad k\geqslant4\;.$

$\color{brown}{\text{Case }1) :}$

If $\;1\leqslant k\leqslant 3\;,\;$ then $\;k=1\;,\;$ indeed

$k=2\implies8=a^2\;$ which is impossible in $\;\mathbb Z_3\;,$

$k=3\implies5x^2+12=a^2\;$ which is impossible in $\;\mathbb Z_5\;.$

Hence, in the first case, it results that

$k=\lambda^2\;$ where $\;\lambda=1\in\mathbb N\,.$

$\color{brown}{\text{Case }2) :}$

From $\;(*)\;,\;$ it follows that $\;4\leqslant k\leqslant x^2\;,\;$ therefore ,

$\big(k\!-\!1\!\big)^2\!x^2<\left(k^2\!-\!4\right)\!x^2<a^2=k^2x^2+4\!\left(k\!-\!x^2\right)\leqslant k^2x^2\;,$

hence ,

$kx-x<a\leqslant kx\;,$

consequently ,

$0\leqslant\dfrac{kx-a}2<\dfrac x2\;.$

Since $\;k^2x^2-a^2=4\left(x^2-k\right)\;$ is an even integer, then $\;k^2x^2\,,\;a^2\;$ are both even integers or $\;k^2x^2\,,\;a^2\;$ are both odd integers, consequently ,

$kx\;,\;a\;$ are both even integers or $\;kx\;,\;a\;$ are both odd integers, but in any case it results that

$kx-a\;$ is an even integer.

Let $\;x_1=\dfrac{kx-a}2\in\mathbb N\cup\big\{0\big\}\;.$

If $\;x_1=0\;,\;$ then $\;a=kx\;$ and $\;k=x^2\;,\;$ therefore

$k=\lambda^2\;$ where $\;\lambda=x\in\mathbb N\;.$

If $\;x_1\geqslant1\;,\;$ it results that

$\begin{align}
&16<\left(k^2-4\right)x_1^2+4k=\\
&=k^2x_1^2-\big(kx-a\big)^2+4k=\\
&=k^2x_1^2-k^2x^2-a^2+2akx+4k=\\
&=k^2x_1^2-k^2x^2-\left(k^2x^2-4x^2+4k\right)+2akx+4k=\\
&=k^2x_1^2-2k^2x^2+4x^2+2akx=\\
&=k^2x_1^2-4kx\left(\dfrac{kx-a}2\right)+4x^2=\\
&=\big(kx_1-2x\big)^2\;.
\end{align}$

Let $\;a_1=\big|kx_1-2x\big|\quad\big(\implies a_1\in\mathbb N\;\land\;a_1>4\big).$

It results that

$\left(k^2-4\right)x_1^2+4k=a_1^2\quad$ where $\quad1\leqslant x_1<\dfrac x2\;.$

Moreover, from $\;(*)\;$ with $\;x=x_1\;$ and $\;a=a_1\;,\;$ it follows that $\;4\leqslant k\leqslant x_1^2\;.$

By proceeding analogously, we obtain two finite sequences $\big\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}\big\}\subseteq\mathbb N\!\cup\!\big\{0\big\}\;$ and $\;\big\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\big\}\subseteq\mathbb N\;$ such that

$\left(k^2-4\right)x_1^2+4k=a_1^2\quad$ where $\quad1\leqslant x_1<\dfrac x2<x\;,$

$\left(k^2-4\right)x_2^2+4k=a_2^2\quad$ where $\quad1\leqslant x_2<\dfrac{x_1}2<x_1\;,$

………………………………………………………………

$\left(k^2-4\right)x_n^2+4k=a_n^2\quad$ where $\quad1\!\leqslant\!x_n\!<\!\dfrac{x_{n-1}}2\!<\!x_{n-1}\,,$

$0=x_{n+1}=\dfrac{kx_n-a_n}2<\dfrac{x_n}2<x_n\;.$

Therefore ,

$a_n=kx_n\;\;$ and $\;\;k=x_n^2\;,$

consequently ,

$k=\lambda^2\;$ where $\;\lambda=x_n\in\mathbb N\;.$

Comment: It is obvious that one of the values of $\,k\,$ such that  $\left(k^2-4\right)x^2+4k=a^2\;\;$ is $\;\;k=x^2\;$ which is a perfect square. Now, I am trying to analyse the case $\,k<x^2$ in order to prove that $\,k\,$ is a perfect square anyway.

Comment: @Sam, $k$ and $x$ are both parameters. The original poster wants us to prove that if $k$ and $x$ are two positive integers such that $(k^2 - 4)x^2 +4k$ is a perfect square, then $k$ is a perfect square too.

Comment: True I misread the original question. Thank you, deleted my comment.

Comment: I have already analysed the case $k\leqslant x^2$ and I have proved that $k$ is a perfect square.

Comment: @Angelo Thank you for finishing the proof! You deserve the bounty.
Did you know that you can solve this problem with enough time? or you were not sure but tried?

Comment: @Angelo I have been asking this for about a year ago but ignored because "Vieta Jumping problem is already fully explained" and the question was closed. Thank you again.

Comment: @Angelo I have thought that checking "V" on your answer gives you bounty automatically. I gave you that. Thanks.