# Solvability of $ax^2 +b = y^2$ under integer, and has infinite solutions.

Tags: number-theory, integers, pell-type-equations

For example,

$3x^2 + 4 = y^2$ has infinite integer solutions while $5x^2 + 12 = y^2$ doesn't.

At first I thought $b$ has to be the perfect square but $3x^2 + 6 = y^2$ has infinite solutions.

So the conditions for solving this equation is going more complicated for me.

I think it has something to do with Pell's equations, but I can't go further.

Comment: For "generalized Pell's equation" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell's_equation

Comment: @GEdgar I can't think of the actual solutions to my original question with that information. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You cannot see that your problem is equivalent to the problem $x^2-dy^2=N$ by re-naming the variables?

Comment: This can help if you are looking to check the existence of a solution of generalised Pell's equation https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4563342/1057393

Comment: @rosefoster Thank you for the suggestion. This question is related to my original question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546638/how-can-i-prove-k2-4x2-4k-can-be-a-perfect-square-only-if-k-is-a-perfe). If you are interested, take a look. thank you.